# 12.04 gnome. Icons dont drag properly

Tags: 12.04, icons

I have a 4 monitor setup with xinerama in seperate X windows. I installed gdm and got rid of the big mouse icon. Somewhere along the way though, icons got screwy. Whenever I try and move them, I have to drag my mouse down for a while. Then the icon appears near the top of the monitor. Side to side doesnt seem to do it.

I'd just like to do a full reinstall of the desktop and start from scratch, not sure how to do that. apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop, then install only did a small amount of data.

Open to other suggestions as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

Copy and run the following commands in the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-cache depends ubuntu-desktop | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | sed '/^$/d' | xargs sudo apt-get install --reinstall --install-recommends --yes
```

This command will reinstall the entire desktop. Then reboot the computer. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Didn't do the trick unfortunately. Still have the gnome style login and the icon issue.

Comment: Looks like it. all of the gnome-* packages i have are 3.2.x or 3.4.x

Comment: No, I'm running it in gnome classic mode.

Comment: would you like to keep gdm or use lightdm

Comment: ive always used gdm. if possible, keeping that would be nice, but im flexible at this point to get it working properly

Comment: What Graphics card do you have?

Comment: nvidia geforce 8800gt. secondary geforce 210